# Angular directive not getting evaluated attributes on time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I've created a simple Angular directive which colorizes an element's background based on a string that you can pass as an attribute. Code below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('proverbial')
        .directive('randomBackgroundColor', Directive);

    Directive.$inject = [ '$timeout' ];

    function Directive($timeout) {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            let hash;
            hash = attrs.text.hashCode();
            //generate color based on the containers' string
            let r = (16711680 & hash) >> 16;
            let g = (65280 & hash) >> 8;
            let b = 255 & hash;
            r = parseInt((r + 255) / 4);
            g = parseInt((g + 255) / 4);
            b = parseInt((b + 255) / 4);
            let color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

            //Add random background class to selected element
            element.css('background-color', color);
        }
    }
})();
```

Interestingly enough, when I use it inside an `ng-repeat`, it works as intended:

```
<div class="text-center clearfix">
    <span class="card" random-background-color text="{{proverb.text}}" ng-repeat="proverb in $ctrl.proverbs">
        <a ui-sref="unrestricted.proverb">{{proverb.text}}</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here you can see the results:

[image]

However when I use the directive by itself (outside an `ng-repeat`) the attribute text does not get evaluated on time, resulting in the directive always colorizing its element with the same color, regardless of the string that I pass it.

What's happening is that when the directive runs, the string `attrs.text` is empty.

Is there any way to solve this **without using `$timeout`**

Comment: You could add `text` to the directive's scope and `$watch` it?

Comment: I've made a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/PWW3UxRA4hlv147wUUy5?p=preview) with your problem and it works. Please, update the plunker and try to reproduce the error. I even used remote data to generate a more real context